# Resources for Game Match in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What would be the best way to architect the model relationships and nested resources to build a game with: Users(from devise), Games, Players(join table w/ Games/Users). My problem is Users exist, but Players need to be created at the same time as games. Creating a game also has to create a player, which is possible but feels icky. Is there a better way to do this? I would like to avoid using transactions or filters to create new resources. Thanks.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook, :twitter]
  has_many :games
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :game,
      message: "can't join your own game" }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :game

  has_one :board
  has_many :ships
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_player, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'first_player_id'
  belongs_to :second_player, class_name: 'Player', foreign_key: 'second_player_id'
  has_one :first_player_board, through: :first_player, source: :board
  has_one :second_player_board, through: :second_player, source: :board
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by doing away with the player model all together and having Users have_many :games.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_player, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'first_player_id'
  belongs_to :second_player, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'second_player_id'
  has_one :first_player_board, through: :first_player, source: :board
  has_one :second_player_board, through: :second_player, source: :board
end
```